# issue with CKEditor (a HTML Editor)

Tags: html, ckeditor

Does anybody know about CKEditor, I have integrated this application in my web app.  The problem i am facing, when i integrate the web page with CKEditor,

```
  CKEDITOR.replace( 'webpage_parent_div_ID' );
```

it's only taking the body innerHTML and doesn't include the CSS & js files ( css & js files described in web page's `<head>` part) of my web page. I know js & css files can be included in CKEditor but not able to figure it out.

Can someone give me idea about it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To include CSS you can use one of these

```
config.contentsCss = '/css/mysitestyles.css';
config.contentsCss = ['/css/mysitestyles.css', '/css/anotherfile.css'];
```

From the documentation: http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.config.html#.contentsCss